# How do I pass function references into my method and use them?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have a working method that I'd like to make more generic using lambdas or function references. That is, for some of the methods that are called within my method, I'd like to specify them as arguments to my method. However I can't quite get it.

Let's say I have the following basic class structure

```
class B {}
class C {
    public Set<Integer> getIds() { ... }
    public void addB(B b) { ... }
}
```

And I have my working method

```
private void p1(Map<Integer, C> cs, Map<Integer, B> bs) {
    for (C c : cs.values()) {
        for (Integer id : c.getIds()) {
            if (bs.containsKey(id)) {
                c.addB(bs.get(id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called thus `p1(cs, bs);` - so far so good.

The first step in making this more generic is to provide a lambda for the `getIds()` method. I have achieved this using:

```
private void p1(Map<Integer, C> cs, Map<Integer, B> bs, Function<C, Set<Integer>> f) {
    for (C c : cs.values()) {
        for (Integer id : f.apply(c)) {  // Change here
            if (bs.containsKey(id)) {
                c.addB(bs.get(id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called thus:  `p1(cs, bs, C::getIds);` - again, so far so good. I am now passing in `getIds()` as an argument to my function and making use of it.

Now I want to provide a lambda for the `addB()` method as the fourth argument to `p1()` and I cannot find the right way. I have tried several things, eg. `Function` and `Consumer<B>`, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `BiConsumer<C,B>` should work:

```
private void p1(Map<Integer, C> cs, Map<Integer, B> bs, Function<C, Set<Integer>> f, BiConsumer<C,B> cons) {
    for (C c : cs.values()) {
        for (Integer id : f.apply(c)) {
            if (bs.containsKey(id)) {
                cons.accept(c,bs.get(id));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can pass the lambda expression `(c,b)->c.addB(b)` or the method reference `C::addB` as the fourth argument of the method.

Comment: @MalteHartwig passing `C::addB` instead of `(c,b)->c.addB(b)` should work (it passes compilation for me).

Comment: Dammit, I was so close. Thanks for the super-quick response. PS: I was able to use `C::addB`.